# On CentOS 8 in profile.d do I need to add my script related to environment variables to both an .sh and .csh file?

Tags: centos, bash, shell-scripting, environment-variables

I need to add environmental variables related to proxy servers to allow my node.js app to communicate with reCAPTCHA Enterprise on Google Cloud.

When I run the scripts from [Accessing Google Cloud APIs though a Proxy](https://medium.com/google-cloud/accessing-google-cloud-apis-though-a-proxy-fe46658b5f2a) communication with Google Cloud is successfully enabled.  However going forward I need proxy support at startup.

```
export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG  
export GRPC_TRACE=handshaker

export HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128
export http_proxy=http://localhost:3128
export https_proxy=http://localhost:3128
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128
```

When I checked my `profile.d` directory I noticed it had both `.sh` and `.csh` files.  For example,

```
colorgrep.csh
colorgrep.sh
colorls.csh
colorls.sh
colorxzgrep.csh
colorxzgrep.sh
colorzgrep.csh
colorzgrep.sh
csh.local
gawk.csh
gawk.sh
lang.csh
lang.sh
less.csh
less.sh
nano.sh
sh.local
which2.csh
which2.sh
```

Do I need to copy and paste my proxy related scripts into a single `.sh` file or should I also add them to a `.csh` file?  Also will a simple copy and paste work or does the format need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the shell that is being used.

`.sh` is for `Bash`. If that is the shell, then those files will be sourced and their contents will be added to users' environments.

`.csh` is for `C Shell` which is an improved version of `tsch`. If `C Shell` is being used, then those files will instead be sourced and the contents added to users' environments.

You can add what you have to an existing file depending on what shell you are using but the best way is to create a new file with the respective extension and add what you have. Make sure that it is readable by all users.